# DELETE и LIMIT в PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Доброго времени суток!

Имеется таблица:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне нужно удалить ровно одну запись из этой таблицы, где `id` равны `1` и `1`.

Если я не ошибаюсь, делается это с помощью LIMIT, но как правильно сформулировать SQL запрос?

Comment: Ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5170546/how-do-i-delete-a-fixed-number-of-rows-with-sorting-in-postgresql

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
delete from x
 where ctid in(select ctid from x
                where id_furniture=1 and id_order=1
                limit 1)
```

`ctid` это специальная системная колонка PostgreSQL содержащая физический адрес записи. А вообще следует исключать такие ситуации в БД. Любая таблица должна иметь уникальный ключ.

Answer (score 2):

**MySQL** умеет так

```
DELETE FROM
  my_table
WHERE
  id_furniture = 1 AND
  id_order = 1
LIMIT 1
```

**PostgreSQL** так не умеет. В нем нужно удалять через подзапрос с использованием псевдополя `ctid`

```
DELETE FROM
  my_table
WHERE
  ctid IN (
    SELECT
      ctid
    FROM
      my_table
    WHERE
      id_furniture = 1 AND
      id_order = 1
    LIMIT 1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот так

```
DELETE FROM ttt WHERE ctid IN (SELECT ctid FROM ttt WHERE id_furniture = 1 AND id_order = 1 LIMIT 1)
```

Comment: Думаю стоит явно описать, что такое `ctid`, т.к. это служебный идентификатор Postgres.